# Different behavior when using Puppeteer vs a real web browser (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape data from a website using Puppeteer and it seems that the page is getting redirected in the session opened with Puppeteer and using a web browser normally.

To be able to understand more what's happening, I am using a headfull browser with the devtools enabled. Once the page gets loaded, I trigger all the user events manually.

If you want to try it this is the code for now :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [`--window-size=1920,1080`],
    defaultViewport: {
      width:1920,
      height:1080
    },
    devtools: true
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://otv.verwalt-berlin.de/ams/TerminBuchen', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
```

Click on "EN" for English, then "Book Appointment".

In the Network tab, it seems that there is a cancelled request in the Puppeteer version. I am sure this has to do something with this issue.

Any idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: You can always set executablePath to a "real browser" or connect to one with puppeteer.connect

Comment: By default, Puppeteer uses chrome from ~/.cache/puppeteer/chrome. I have tried launching manually and got the same result as in a real browser. So I guess the issue has to be somewhere in the config of Puppeteer.

Comment: You can launch it manually and then connect to it with puppeteer.connect if it's doing what you want.

Comment: Your code works as expected for me - no redirect.

Comment: @ChristophSchellhaus The main page works fine. But if you try clicking on "EN" then "Book Appointment" the page will get redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `waitForNetworkIdle()` after each click of the navigation. This will resolve if all requests on the page is stopped (becomes idle).

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://otv.verwalt-berlin.de/ams/TerminBuchen', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
await page.click('div.lang-link > a'); // button for language
await page.waitForNetworkIdle()
await page.click('div.text > div:nth-child(4) > a'); // button for book appointment
await page.waitForNetworkIdle()
// ...and then wait for other forms/elements on the page
```

This will make sure the page is loaded properly before clicking the next element.

In your particular example, you can even open the final page directly with specific URL. I could easily get the url right clicking the element.

```
https://otv.verwalt-berlin.de/ams/TerminBuchen/wizardng?sprachauswahl=en
```